# Why VueJs introduce .native Event modifier ? What are the use case of this? - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I din't get any docs for `native` event modifiers. I have seen some where like this:

```
<router-link @click.native="pressThis()"> Press here </router-link>
```

what is the use of `native` modifier on `router-link` click `event`.
and what other use case `native` modifier can have ?

Comment: I am not sure, I am just supposing that native modifier is something like an alias for isTrusted event property, i.e. event callback will be fired only if the event was fired native way and not programatically. In other words, do not react to the synthetic - untrusted event.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `.native` is no longer necessary in Vue 3.

Answer (score 34):

You can override Vue events in custom components. For instance, you might have a list component that once you click an item you call `this.$emit('click', selectedItemData)`, and that will emit the click event to the parent component that is watching that.

However, sometimes you really want to bind to the native HTML/DOM event listener `element.addEventListener('click', callThisMethod)`, and that's the use of `.native`. Also, make a note that it will handle cleaning the event listener once your component gets destroyed just like a non-native event.

In sum: use `.native` when you need the 'raw' event from DOM.

Comment: I hear you when you say `.native` is used when I need the raw event from the DOM. I recently encountered a weird case though, where – depending where I use a button component – `.native` is not triggered. I described this here: https://cutt.ly/xrCmp7M.
Do you have any thoughts or explanation on that? Thank you in advance.